# Is there a package or function that can do SMOTE with continuous and categorical features?

Tags: r, classification, resampling, oversampling

I have an unbalanced data set with a categorical dependent variable and feature variables that are continuous and categorical. I know that the SMOTE function from the DMwR package can handle only continuous features. Is there package that can handle categorical and continuous features like Chawla describes [in his paper](https://www.jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10302/24590)?

Comment: Not in R, but it seems that it has been implemented in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655813/oversampling-smote-for-binary-and-categorical-data-in-python

Comment: My reading of the paper that you cite covers only continuous features. In particular, note that when describing the "Adult" dataset, they wrote `For SMOTE, we extracted the continuous features and generated a new
dataset with only continuous features.`

Comment: It's under section 6.1 and 6.2 @G5W. But just in theory.

Comment: @RLave yes, i know but i hope maybe someone can help me out with r implementation

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that it's not yet implemented in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in R!

Yes, both smotefamily::SMOTE and DMwR::SMOTE can only handle numeric features because the underlying algorithm is k-nearest neighbors.

Therefore:

1. convert all categorical variables to datatype `factor`.
2. calculate numeric estimates of each factor level by the very recent package `tidymodels::embed`

The `tidymodels::embed` package offers three methods to perform step 2:

- step_lencode_glm
- step_lencode_bayes
- step_lencode_mixed

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/embed/embed.pdf) says that these methods 
`estimate the effect of each of the factor levels on the outcome and these estimates are used as the new encoding.`

Comment: DMwR package has been removed from CRAN